# Grouping elements in a list such that each seed produces unique combination

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have a unique problem . Let us consider we have a list of elements [1,2,3,4,5,6] .  I need to select certain set of elements to form pools based on the pool size. i.e. if pool size is 3 and my list size is 6 then there are total 6C3 possible combinations possible. This can be done by random sample

But here is the catch lets say I have a bigger list and I have to group all the members in the list such that all of them are present in a group for one iteration(lets call this seed).
Now for the next seed I will again group the elements in a different combinations but the combinations I get must be unique from the combinations I got in the previous seed.

Example:
elements are [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
Now my pool size is 3
my seeds 3

```
seed1-'[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]'

seed2-'[[1,5,3],[4,2,6],[7,11,9],[10,8,12],[13,17,15],[16,14,18]]'

seed3-'[[1,5,6],[4,2,3],[7,11,12],[10,8,9],[13,17,18],[16,14,15]]'
```

Note that all elements must be present once in a seed and none of the combinations in any of the seeds must be repeated. It may look simple for small set of elements but Iam trying to implement this on a element size of 300 with 500 seeds

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I actually have no clue where to start I tried random sampling with few condition checks but they will produce duplicates across seeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the number of seeds you generate does not come close to exhausting the possible combinations, what you can do is a shuffle of the whole list of numbers that you then break down in chunks of the pool size.  Then keep track of the pools used so far and generate another shuffle when you have a conflict.

This can be done in a generator function so that you don't need to predetermine the number of seeds you're going to generate:

```
from random import sample
def seedPools(elements,poolSize):
    used = set()
    while True:
        shuffled = sample(elements,len(elements))
        seed     = [ tuple(shuffled[i:i+poolSize]) 
                     for i in range(0,len(elements),poolSize)]
        if any(pool in used for pool in seed): continue
        yield seed
        used.update(seed)
```

Sample output:

```
seedGen = seedPools(list(range(1,19)),3)
for _ in range(10): print(next(seedGen))
                 
    
[(9, 13, 18), (10, 15, 12), (14, 16, 2), (3, 1, 17), (4, 5, 8), (6, 11, 7)]
[(16, 7, 6), (14, 12, 5), (15, 4, 17), (3, 10, 8), (9, 11, 2), (13, 18, 1)]
[(6, 8, 7), (10, 9, 15), (2, 1, 14), (17, 18, 12), (11, 3, 4), (5, 16, 13)]
[(12, 1, 3), (6, 5, 16), (2, 14, 9), (7, 8, 15), (10, 13, 11), (17, 4, 18)]
[(7, 14, 12), (4, 10, 13), (9, 17, 5), (16, 3, 2), (1, 11, 18), (8, 15, 6)]
[(18, 13, 10), (12, 1, 14), (8, 6, 15), (3, 2, 5), (16, 9, 11), (17, 4, 7)]
[(6, 5, 12), (8, 2, 13), (1, 15, 14), (17, 10, 7), (3, 11, 4), (16, 9, 18)]
[(14, 6, 1), (11, 5, 18), (12, 10, 16), (8, 13, 17), (15, 9, 2), (4, 7, 3)]
[(10, 16, 11), (1, 15, 5), (4, 3, 12), (6, 14, 2), (17, 18, 9), (7, 8, 13)]
[(11, 10, 1), (12, 8, 14), (17, 13, 6), (18, 7, 5), (9, 15, 4), (3, 16, 2)]
```

To generate 500 seeds from 300 items, you can use a list comprehension (or you could add a parameter to the generator function)

```
seedGen  = seedPools(list(range(1,301)),3)
bigSeeds = [ next(seedGen) for _ in range(500) ] # 0.14 second on my computer
```

*Note: I assumed that you don't want any of the pools to repeat across seeds.  If the pools are allowed to repeat, then you only need to check `if tuple(seed) in used: continue` to try another shuffle, and of course record the whole seed instead of individual pools in the `used`set after yielding a unique seed: `used.add(tuple(seed))`*

[EDIT] Here is the function adjusted to spread extra values to random pools so that all pools have at least the requested pool size:

```
from random import sample
def seedPools(elements,poolSize,seedCount):
    used = set()
    while seedCount > 0:
        shuffled = sample(elements,len(elements))
        seed     = [ tuple(shuffled[i:i+poolSize]) 
                     for i in range(0,len(elements),poolSize)]
        if len(seed[-1])<poolSize:
            lastPool = seed.pop(-1)
            spread   = sample(range(len(seed)),len(lastPool))
            for p,v in zip(spread,lastPool):
                seed[p] += (v,)
        if any(pool in used for pool in seed): continue
        yield seed
        used.update(seed)
        seedCount -= 1

for seed in seedPools(list(range(1,20)),3,10): print(seed)

[(14, 11, 18), (2, 12, 9), (8, 3, 4), (7, 6, 13), (16, 17, 15), (1, 19, 10, 5)]
[(9, 15, 11), (1, 3, 2), (14, 10, 19), (8, 5, 12, 7), (6, 16, 4), (18, 17, 13)]
[(19, 10, 18), (5, 9, 2), (4, 1, 6, 16), (13, 11, 15), (12, 8, 17), (14, 7, 3)]
[(1, 5, 15, 12), (2, 6, 14), (18, 8, 11), (16, 13, 19), (3, 17, 4), (10, 7, 9)]
[(7, 14, 8), (12, 18, 6, 2), (17, 9, 16), (15, 5, 3), (13, 11, 10), (4, 19, 1)]
[(15, 6, 17), (2, 10, 3), (7, 19, 16, 9), (4, 11, 5), (8, 13, 12), (14, 1, 18)]
[(1, 16, 2), (19, 14, 18), (12, 17, 5, 7), (13, 11, 4), (9, 6, 3), (15, 10, 8)]
[(2, 17, 19), (8, 13, 5, 18), (7, 11, 1), (16, 15, 6), (14, 12, 4), (10, 3, 9)]
[(3, 12, 7, 15), (4, 11, 2), (17, 1, 14), (19, 10, 6), (13, 9, 5), (18, 8, 16)]
[(13, 15, 12), (9, 1, 18), (5, 3, 10), (16, 4, 14), (11, 17, 7), (19, 2, 6, 8)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your .This is exactly how I  solved it  . But my only worry is if the elements is small and the pool size is small then the "if tuple(seed) in used: continue" might start running in a loop the more closer Iam to the maximum seed possible for the data the more time it will take to find a unique seed. I was thinking is there a way to run the algo only the specified number of seeds and not more.

Comment: Also a corner case would be if my element list is not divisible by the pool size then I need all the remaining elements in the seed to be put into random pools in that seed.

Comment: Added a revised version to cover that corner case. See [EDIT]

Comment: As for running the algorithm a specific number of seed, that's already what the example show.  You can compute the theoretical maximum by counting combinations (see https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php).  For example for 18 values in 6 pools of 3, the maximum would be 18nCr3 / 6 = 136 if you use distinct pools or 18! = 6402373705728000 if you use distinct seeds. You are unlikely to run into performance problems unless you go beyond 80% of these numbers

Comment: Took pretty much the same route after some non-random detours. At first I was a bit concerned that it would slow down too quick, but 500 seeds is far from a speed problem.